# PostgreSql not coming to database from Django project

Tags: django, database, postgresql, docker-compose

I am using PostgreSql as database in my Django project. When I run it locally via pgAdmin, the data appears, but when I run it on the server, the data does not come in pgAdmin.

Django settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'xxxx',
    'USER' : 'xxx',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
    'HOST': 'pgdb',
    'PORT': 5432,
}
```

}

docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
# CaddyServer reverse proxy
caddy:
    restart: always
    image: caddy:2-alpine
    ports:
        - "443:443"
    command: caddy reverse-proxy --from https://xxxxxx.com --to http://0.0.0.0:8000
    #volumes:
    #    - /local/path/to/Caddyfile:/path/inside/continer/to/Caddyfile
    #     networks:
    #   - web
    #   - bridge

# Django web app
django:
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
    #environment:
    #    - url=https://api.backend.example.com
    #command: "gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    #networks:
    #   - bridge
pgdb:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=xxxx
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxxx
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxx
    volumes: 
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

volumes:
pg-data:

I am connecting via pgAdmin server ip. The pgAdmin connection is established, but the data I entered into the system is not visible on pgAdmin.

Comment: I would recomend to add some more info: version of the software/DB that you use. Where does your connection pass (proxy/FW) some concrete error that appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### That's because it's not inside your postgres database, but only in pg_admin

What I'd suggest you to do is to run this command via ssh to get a list of databases:

```
psql -l
```

Once you get all the db names, and its owners, check if your db appears. If it does, try accessing it with:

```
psql -U your_db_username || psql -U your_db_username -d your_db_name
```

Access and query your tables to see if the data is indeed there.

If it's not there, what I would suggest is to dump the db with:

```
pg_dump -U db_username db_name > your_backup.pgsql
```

Afterwards, you should restore that dump through the terminal into postgres:

```
psql -U db_username --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on -f your_backup.pgsql
```

Let me know if this helped you. I can further assist you on this one if it does help in the end but you face new/other problems.